# MYSQL TRIGGER: select columns of the row where i have the updated value

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this trigger. I want to select two columns values of the row i've just updated only if the column 'confirm' is updated with the '1' value.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `order_confirm` BEFORE UPDATE ON `order`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  DECLARE c_id_order INT; DECLARE order_date DATE;

  IF(NEW.confirm<>OLD.confirm) THEN

     SELECT id_order, order.date INTO c_id_order, order_date FROM order  
     WHERE NEW.confirm = 1;

     CALL function_name(c_id_order, order_date);

   END IF;  

 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

this is the error message:Result consisted of more than one row. 
Thank you a lot.

Comment: You already know the values for `id_order` and `order.date`. They are: `new.id_order` and `new.date`. Use these instead of querying them.

Comment: thank you.  is it valid also if i only update the column confirm?

Comment: ok it works. i use OLD to be sure